# PHP - call class from class

Tags: php

Hello i looking for a way to call class function from another class.

i've tried diffrent PHP ways such as the classic way, to call class from class.

http://pastebin.com/X5VfaChr

```
require_once "user.php";
$user = new UserAction();
class htmloutput{
    public function WebSite(){
        $user->Moshe();
    }
}
```

Its shows me this error:" syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)" i dont know about more ways to call a class.

I'll be happy to get helping and
learn somethin' from that.

Have Good day,
Baruch

Comment: check if the class file user.php is closed i.e. the last `}` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the instance inside your function, as the following:

```
require_once 'user.php';
class htmloutput {
    public function WebSite(){
        $user = new UserAction();
        $user->Moshe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i put $user = new UserAction(); inside the class and not in function. because i call him for few questions?. Thanks.

Comment: You can make it to be initialized in constructor, and share between all the functions of the class, for instance: 

require_once 'user.php'; 
class htmloutput { 
   public $user; 
   public function __construct() { 
      $this->user = new UserAction(); 
   } 
   public function WebSite(){ 
      $this->user->Moshe(); 
   } 
   public function otherAction() { 
      $this->user->something(); 
   } 
}

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comment from  Abhik Chakraborty, this fixes the issue coming next:

It's all about scope. Google for `DI injection`:

```
require_once "user.php";
$user = new UserAction();

class htmloutput {
    public function WebSite(UserAction $user) {
        $user->Moshe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i put $user = new UserAction(); inside the class and not in function. because i call him for few questions?. Thanks.